# While loop : Stuck at one point

Tags: python, while-loop

How to find the sum of all the negative numbers in this list

I created below code:

```py
given_list3 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]
total7 = 0
i = 0
while i < len(given_list3) and given_list3[i] < 0:
    total7 += given_list3[i]
    i += 1
print(total7)
```

Not sure why it is giving me a zero. Please help.

Comment: Try to run it by hand and see when your loop ends.

Comment: Because the condition given_list3[i] < 0 is false.

Comment: Print in your loop the avriables : `i`, `given_list3`, `total7`, it will help you debug.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in given code is that it stops running as soon as it starts. This is because of condition:

`while i < len(given_list3) and given_list3[i] < 0`

When it checks first element for condition even though `i < len(given_list3)` is true but `given_list3[i] < 0` is false. As there is `and` between both conditions so it means both conditions **have to be true** for loop to run else it will exit right away.
Additionally, If in your code calculation is only happening in one line then you can do:

```
while i < len(given_list3):
    total7 += ((given_list3[i] < 0)*given_list3[i])
    i += 1
```

In code `(given_list3[i] < 0)` becomes 1 (True) if i is less than 0 otherwise it becomes 0 (false). So all positive components are eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your `while` loop with this

```
while i < len(given_list3):
    if given_list3[i]<0:
        total7 += given_list3[i]
    i += 1
print(total7)
```

In your code, `i=0`. When you do `given_list[i]` it means `given_list[0]` as `i=0`. But the first number is 7. And according to the loop, it should iterate **only** if `i` is less than length of the list *and* **`given_list[i]`** is less than `0`. But 7 is greater than 0 and it just skips the loop. Hence you get the output as 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension

```
given_list3 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]
sum([i for i in given_list3 if i<0])
-17
```

Answer (score -2):

I am glad that i am able to answer this question,
So answer of this question is-
Better you use for loop and give if condition inside for loop.
I hope this will help you for your question.

Comment: Thanks, yes I used for loop, just wanted to get same answer with While loop. Got the answer now.